# Trying to match full word in Advantage Database local server search

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I have a client whose app uses Advantage Database's Local Server (ALS). I'm trying to match full words in searches. I was hoping to use something like this:

```
select * from mytable 
where column1 like '%[ .,/?!@#$%^&*()-]searchstring[ .,/?!@#$%^&*()-]%'
```

Apparently the local server does not handle brackets at all.

How can I do this?

Comment: Advantage doesn't support regular expressions. It supports standard SQL wildcards (% and _), or full text search expressions using CONTAINS(). It's somewhat unclear what you're asking. Can you show some actual content that you're trying to match (some actual field values and what you're trying to match within it)?

Comment: For example, I want to search for "head" and not find "forehead". I do want to find "fore-head" or "head-ache" or "head/neck".

Comment: That's going to be very difficult to do using SQL alone. You may be able to do it with a couple of LIKE terms and then an OnFilterRecord event to do the fine-tuning.